ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
I am getting the error . I am struggling as totally a newbie in the React world. Not sure what is messed up in the code. Any help please? Using Graphql 4 with Next.js and typescript. Have typedef, resolver and route.ts and also Apollo client .
    null
     ⨯ node_modules\@apollo\client\errors\index.js (39:0) @ new ApolloError
     ⨯ ApolloError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

 Route.ts

const graphql = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
   
  }); 

 const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(graphql);  
export async function GET(request: Request) {
      return handler(request);
    }        
    export async function POST(request: Request) {
      return handler(request); 
    }
 typedef.ts
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";

const userQuery = gql`
  type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    email: String!    
  }

  type Query {
    getUser(id: ID!): User
  }  
`;

export default userQuery;   

resolver.ts

import data from './data.json';

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
     getUsers: () => {
        return data 
     }
    },    
  };    
  export default resolvers;
   data.json
   [
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alice", "email": "alice@example.com" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob", "email": "bob@example.com" }
  ]

